# Constructing a basis of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way to construct the basis of a, say, $k$ - dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, from the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Edit: Taking a note from the comments, let me provide with an example to show what I mean by construction. Consider the $1$ - dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R^n} = \{(x,\cdots,x) \ \vert \ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Here the basis is $(1,\cdots,1)$, which is nothing but $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i$. Therefore, the basis can be constructed from the standard basis.

Can I say that for any $k$ - dimensional subspace, $k<n$?

Comment: what is your doubt

Comment: Can we construct a basis of a k-dim subspace from the standard basis?

Comment: Let $n>1$, let $k=1$.  Consider the $1$-dimensional space of all vectors $(x,x,x,\ldots,x)\in\mathbb R^n$.  This space contains none of elements of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$.  So one answer to your question is *no*.  Another is *yes*, because every vector in any basis of your $k$-subspace is a linear combo of standard basis elements of  $\mathbb R^n$.  Please rephrase your question so we know what you are really asking.

Comment: Well, in your example, the basis of that space is $(1,1,\cdots,1) \in \mathbb {R}^n$, which is nothing but the sum of all standard basis. Which is what I mean by construction.

Comment: No, that’s just *one* basis for the space. $\{(2,2,\dots,2)\}$ is another perfectly good basis for it. What criteria are you using to decide that your choice of basis is *the* basis for the space?

Comment: I am not. I'm asking, is there a choice of basis that can be constructed from the standard basis. And if it can, is there any algorithm to do it. 

I know the basis for any subspace is not unique.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to prove this - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505798/showing-that-the-union-of-the-given-charts-is-the-whole-manifold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to obtain an answer.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a subspace of dimension $k$, and basis $b_1, \cdots, b_k$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a matrix with $b_i$s as columns. i.e. $\mathcal{B} = (b_1 \cdots b_k)$.

Since the columns are independent. We can diagonalise the submatrix of order $k \times k$ to obtain a similar matrix $\mathcal{B'} = \begin{pmatrix} I_k \\ M \end{pmatrix}$, where $M \in M_{(n-k) \times k}(\mathbb{R})$, and $M=(x_{ij})_{ij}, 1\leq i\leq n-k$ ; $1\leq j\leq k$. Therefore obtaining a basis $a_1, \cdots a_k$; where $a_j = e_j + x_{j,1}\cdot e_{k+1}+ \cdots+x_{j,n-k}\cdot e_n$