# Showing that the union of the given charts is the whole manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $G(n,k)$ be the set of all $k$ - dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $U_I$ be the set of all subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ having a basis $a_1, \cdots, a_k$ such that $a_i=e_i + x_{i,1}\cdot e_{k+1}+\cdots +x_{i,n-k}\cdot e_{n}$, where $x_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$, and $e_j$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  $I$ runs through the set of all subsets $I \subset \{1,\cdots,n\}, \#I=k$.

Let $x_I(A)=(x_{ij}, i = 1,\cdots,n; j=1,\cdots,n-k)\in \mathbb{R}^{n(n-k)}$. Show that $\{(U_I, \mathbb{R}^{n(n-k)} ,x_I)\}$ is an atlas in $G(n,k)$.

Now, to start proving that the given collection is an atlas, first step would be to show that $\bigcup_IU_I=G(n,k)$. Clearly, $\bigcup_IU_I\subseteq G(n,k)$.

To show that, $G(n,k) \subseteq \bigcup_IU_I$, we need to show that any $k$ - dimensional subspace $A$ can have a basis of the form $b_i = e_i + x_{i,1}\cdot e_{k+1}+\cdots +x_{i,n-k}\cdot e_{n}$, where $i=1,\cdots,k$ ; $x_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$, and $e_j$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. How do I show that without knowing what $A$ looks like?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Interpreting the definition more geometrically, $U_I$ consists of the subspaces that are the graph of some function $\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^{n - k}$, where we identify $\mathbb R^k$ with $\langle e_i : i \in I\rangle$ and $\mathbb R^{n - k}$ with $\langle e_j : j \not\in I\rangle$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to follow

Comment: Can you be more specific? The point is that a subspace $A$ is a graph of some function $\Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R^{n - k}$ as in the hint iff the subspace $A$ is transverse to $\Bbb R^{n - k}$. So, to prove the claim it's enough to show that for any $A$ there some coordinate plane $\Bbb R^{n - k}$ transverse to $A$.

Comment: But if $A$ is a graph of the function you mentioned, isn't $A$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n(n-k)}$?

Comment: The graph of a function $X \to Y$ is a subset of $X \times Y$, so in this case $A$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^k \times \Bbb R^{n - k} \cong \Bbb R^n$.